# Reference needed for solving Boundary Value Problems where Eigenvalues are computed numerically

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Recently, I have been trying to solve some boundary value problem where the eigen values are computed numerically. Now when the eigenvalues are trigonometric functions then one uses orthogonality to determine the unknown coefficients. But I cannot fathom how one should proceed forward in a case where these eigenvalues are computed numerically (for example for a third order characteristic equation). How should the Eigenfunctions be created and orthogonality be then used ?

It would be really helpful if the Mathematica SE community could point out to some references where such problems have been dealt with in a step-by-step manner. It would be best if these could be questions asked here on Mathematica SE otherwise, a book or any journal publication. The standard PDE textbooks normally do not discuss such problems. Hope I have been clear regarding what I need, please feel free to clarify any misconception by pointing out in the comments

Answer (score 3):

I don't know much about what *Mathematica* does internally, but you might want to start with the  documentation where there are excellent well presented examples that you can play with.

https://wolfram.com/xid/0btofzo9ibr2-d3ex

[image]

... and with respect to orthogonality there's this:
https://wolfram.com/xid/0btofzo9ibr2-nnzxtv

[image]